# WebForms site with Identity leaving off ".aspx" in auto-redirect URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I've a WebForms site that uses ASP.NET Identity for authentication. If I haven't logged in to the site, it automatically tries to redirect me to the Login page. However, it's leaving off the ".aspx" part of the URL, so I'm left with `http://localhost:10684/Login?ReturnUrl=...`. Since the user doesn't have access to `/Login` (without the .aspx), it auto-redirects again, and again, and again, until Chrome stops it saying there's a redirect loop.

Could I get some insight into what might be causing this?

Here's the full URL I'm left with after it gets stopped when trying to go to `http://localhost:10684/Default.aspx`:

`http://localhost:10684/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252FDefault.aspx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your web.config's authentication settings, e.g.:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Login" />
</authentication>
```

It might be missing the `.aspx` extension:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Likewise, if the redirect URL is instead defined in a code-behind somewhere, check that the extension was provided. Search for instances of `/Login` or `~/Login` in your source code to see where it might be referenced.

Comment: Ah. That was it. It was being set in the `OwinStartup` class. Thanks.